# using AngularJS slider for getting date input as range

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, angular-material

I am working with AngularJs and AngularMaterials and i want the user in my application to define the date input as a range in something in the following format(2016-01-01T00:00:00). How can a AngularJS slider be modified to be used for date inputs?

Comment: have you tried any code? Please provide the example you have tried.

Comment: @AgamBanga https://jsfiddle.net/ajdno6gc/

Comment: seems like there is some js error in your fiddle

Comment: @AgamBanga this is the code which i want to modify to create a slider for fetching range of date in the format as mentioned above. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/avGJGp?editors=1010

Comment: Please check if the answer works for you

Comment: @AgamBanga thanks but to an extent. As i want to get a date range 
(2009-01-01---2015-01-01) which is not happening. also currently only the month value is changing not the day and year. is there a way to change them in a way which is easier to understand for the user too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144264/discussion-between-rehan-and-agam-banga).

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/agamb/954eve2L/1618/   let me know if it works for you

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: @AgamBanga it would be better if you could please edit your answer to the latest version which is more appropriate to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added an example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8x6wfa3n/)

**HTML**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.js"></script>
<div ng-app="rzSliderDemo">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="wrapper">
        <article>
            <rzslider  rz-slider-model="slider.minValue"
          rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue"
          rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>
        </article>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $modal) {
var date1 = new Date(2017, 3, 1);
var date2 = new Date();
var day;
var dateArray = [date1];
while(date1 <= date2) {
    day = date1.getDate()
    date1 = new Date(date1.setDate(++day));  
    dateArray.push(date1);
}
$scope.slider = {
   minValue: dateArray[0],
  maxValue: dateArray[dateArray.length-1],
  value: dateArray[0], // or new Date(2016, 7, 10) is you want to use different instances
  options: {
    stepsArray: dateArray,
    translate: function(date) {
      if (date != null)
        return date.toISOString();
      return '';
    }
  }
};
});
```

Comment: Could see this link?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350964/make-32-hrs-range-in-rzslider-in-angular-js

Comment: It seems some things have changed in jsfiddle since this was posted and the original now gets angular module errors, I made a fixed version here: https://jsfiddle.net/8x6wfa3n/

Comment: Hi @EduardoWada, i have updated the link provided. Thanks for informing. :)